# Launch bootstrap modal on success using formvalidation.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation.io

I have a form which can take a long time to submit, as it posts data to several APIs. This is not a problem in itself.

Usually, I launch a bootstrap modal with a message telling the user to be patient and not click their back button. This is attached to the form's button click event as below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn-wait").click(function(){
            $('#modal-wait').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})  
        });
    });
```

I have just implemented form validation using FormValidation.io however I am having issues getting the modal to launch.

I have tried...

```
$('#myform').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    fields: {
        .......
    }
})
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
    $('#modal-wait').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});  
});
```

This launches the modal however it also stops the form being submitted

From what I can see, anything in .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {  stops the form being submitted.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not trigger your modal on submit event?

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $('#modal-wait').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
})
```